# One line boolean pattern matching in Scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Is there a way to write this code in a more elegant way in Scala?

Basically I have the following algebraic data type:

```
trait Exp
case class Atom(i: Int) extends Exp
case class Add(l: Exp, r: Exp) extends Exp
```

and I want to check if a given variable matches a specific term inside
a conditional expression. For example I can write

```
val x = Add(Atom(1), Atom(2))

if (x match { case Add(Atom(1), Atom(2)) => true; case _ => false }) {
   println("match")
}
```

However, it's ugly and verbose. Is there a more elegant alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `PartialFunction` and its `isDefinedAt` method:

```
type MatchExp = PartialFunction[Exp, Unit]  // alias

val isOnePlusTwo: MatchExp = {
  case Add(Atom(1), Atom(2)) =>
}

if (isOnePlusTwo.isDefinedAt(x)) println("match")
```

A `match` expression produces either a `Function` or a `PartialFunction`, depending on the expected type. The type alias is only for convenience here.

---

Another possibility, if you do not need de-structuring through the pattern match, is to simply rely on the equality of the expression:

```
if (x == Add(Atom(1), Atom(2))) println("match")
```

This works because you use `case class`es which have correct equality implementations.

Comment: The "normally" comment isn't right; you must have an expected type either Func or PF. Also, the helper methods in my answer, which have been around forever but keep a low profile, look much better, even if they will never be hip.

Comment: @som-snytt you are right, I removed the wrong sentence.

Answer (score 4):

Use these for concision:

```
scala> import PartialFunction._
import PartialFunction._

scala> condOpt(x) { case Add(Atom(x), Atom(y)) => x + y }
res2: Option[Int] = Some(3)

scala> cond(x) { case Add(Atom(x), Atom(y)) => println("yep"); true }
yep
res3: Boolean = true

scala> List(x, Atom(42)) flatMap (condOpt(_) { case Add(Atom(x), Atom(y)) => x + y })
res4: List[Int] = List(3)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could put the `println` into the `match` and get rid of the `if` entirely:

```
x match {
  case Add(Atom(1), Atom(2)) => println("match")
  case _ => {} //do nothing
}
```